# OS Concepts in Layman Terms

Tags: blocking, conditional-statements, operating-system, spinning

What is the difference between the following concepts in layman terms: spinning lock, blocking and condition?

Comment: Smells like homework to me.  What's the practical reason for this question?

Comment: I don't take OS. My gf's having problems understanding the concepts as she's revising for her midterms. Honest to God that's the reason.

Comment: That still qualifies as homework; just not yours :).

Comment: You're on SO. So you can't possibly have an SO (Significant Other). LIAR!!!!

Comment: Wait I didn't quite catch that joke... the one bout me being on SO. Why am I on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If your GF doesn't already know this, she should be made aware that CS colleges are the most prolific users of plagarism detection software in the free world.)

Spinning lock:

To quote Lisa and Bart:  "Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?" - cute in small quantities, extremely annoying in large doses.

Blocking:

The gate at the starting line of a horse track, or the locked door at a store before a product launch work as examples of blocking operations.  You can't get your new iPad until some guy in a black t-shirt opens the door.

Condition:

Don't do anything (or keep doing what you're doing) until you hear otherwise from me.